# Why is this !important CSS value overridden?

Tags: javascript, css

HTML:

```
<div id="test">This is a test</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('test');

elem.style.setProperty('color', 'green', 'important');
elem.style.color = 'red';
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/4fn6h/3/

The text is green in Chrome, Safari, and IE9, but red in Firefox, and Opera. (Also, the text is black in IE7, and IE8, because the code throws an error, but let's ignore that... )

So, which browsers follow the standard here? Should it be possible to override a `setProperty(...,'important')` or not?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462537/overriding-important-style-using-javascript

Comment: http://quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html#t46

Comment: interesting, this also happen with http://jsfiddle.net/4fn6h/4/

Comment: @Diodeus That thread didn't help `:(`

Comment: @jbabey That link didn't help `:(`

Comment: Sure seems to me like Firefox's behavior would be preferred. A property can't have two values, right?

Comment: @cliffsofinsanity I assume that Chrome/Safari/IE9 treat a property with an `!important` value as read-only, so it cannot be overwritten, so they just disregard the second assignment...

Comment: @cliffsofinsanity But the problem is: which style should take effect, the one that was assigned last or the one with the highest priority?

Comment: @EvanMulawski: But there's only one style. It's just that its value is being changed. At least that's how I would imagine it would be interpreted.

Comment: @cliffsofinsanity He probably meant "value", not "style"...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: I'm guessing the opposite, that Chrome and the others make the value readonly when the style is marked as important. That wouldn't seem like a reasonable expectation.

Comment: @cliffsofinsanity But that's what I said `:)`. If the value has the "important" flag set, the property becomes read-only.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Yeah, I just realized I had misinterpreted your comment. :)

Comment: ...in any case, it doesn't seem like a reasonable approach to make "important" such that it's current value is more important than a future value on the same element. Seems that "important" should only affect cascading.

Comment: ...Chrome behaves like Firefox if you don't change approaches in the assignment. http://jsfiddle.net/4fn6h/7/ So Chrome indeed does seem to see `elem.style.color...` as inferior to `elem.style.setProp...`

Comment: @cliffsofinsanity `elem.style.color = ...` is inferior because the priority flag cannot be set with it. If you "turn off" the priority in `setProperty()`, it won't have effect in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/4fn6h/10/ *** Wait a minute... Why is the color blue in Firefox?

Comment: So Chrome won't let you revert importance once set. Well that's just great... Firefox should be blue, because the local "important" on the element has been set to `null`, and the stylesheet one now takes priority.

Comment: @cliffsofinsanity Ah yes. This means that Firefox is doing it right.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Yes, it's approach seems most reasonable. I'd consider the others to be buggy.

Comment: So, we can basically forget about `setProperty(...,'important')` since it's not cross-browser `:(`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Seems that a workaround in Chrome is to use `.removeProperty()` before setting the new value. http://jsfiddle.net/4fn6h/12/

Comment: Target Chrome and others with some feature detection, and this fix seems to work. http://jsfiddle.net/4fn6h/15/ ...oh, you'll need to encorporate `getPropertyPriority` so that it doesn't wipe out the priority when one is not sent in the update.

Comment: @cliffsofinsanity Wait a minute... What has more priority than a value set inline? Nothing, right? Then, what's the point of having the priority as a third parameter of `setProperty`? I mean, if `!important` is really only for cascade, and if `setProperty` sets the property inline, then there is no point. I am talking about Chrome here. Firefox does it right and `setProperty(...,'important')` and `setProperty(...,null)` behave differently.

Comment: Except that an "!important" in a stylesheet overrides the inline style. I assume that's the reason for having "important" available directly on the element. ...wait, maybe I'm misunderstanding again.

Comment: @cliffsofinsanity Uh, my last question is not correct. Of course, an !important value in the CSS file has more priority than a regular inline value. This is a good example of how Chrome is doing it wrong - in the 10. demo (http://jsfiddle.net/4fn6h/10/), the text color should be blue (because the "blue" value is !important), but it's green in Chrome (even though we removed the !important flag from the inline value). I'm not 100% sure, though...

Comment: Right, that's where removing the property entirely before setting its new value seems to be the only way for Chrome to emulate what we assume to be a correct behavior. Once Chrome sees "important", that style property basically locked down permanently unless destroyed.

Comment: ...then there's the unfortunate fact of Firefox requiring all 3 arguments. Seems like a general fix could be used to overcome all these issues.

Comment: @cliffsofinsanity Yes, a cross-browser function. That's usually what jQuery does. However, not in this case (since it doesn't recognize `!important`).

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129304/important-overridden

Comment: @cliffsofinsanity, `!important` does not make it read only. user css with `!important` should override `!important` in author css. this is done for accessibility over control. user reading the content should have the absolute power to change how the content is presented.

Answer (score 2):

The spec is not clear. There are two ways to look at it:

1. it's a bug in WebKit/IE9. If you are overwriting the `color` value, there is no reason for the old value to stay around, *important* or not.
2. WebKit/IE9 are correct. The DOM interface `style` manipulates the `style` property of the element, which is considered a [CSS Declaration Block](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-CSS2-19980512/syndata.html#block). In a CSS block, a property with `!important` set will *always* take precedence over ones without. By that rule the change to 'red' should have no effect, so it's effectively ignored.

I believe the latter is the most likely explanation. Consider having a declaration like this:

```css
p { color: red !important; }
```

If you add a second `color` rule, without `!important`, it has no effect:

```css
p {
  color: red !important;
  color: blue;
}
/* the color is still red */
```

The same applies to manipulating the HTML `style` attribute directly.

So the behavior in Chrome/Safari/IE9 is consistent with the CSS cascading rules, while FF and Opera are treating DOM style as a simple object without regard for the cascading rules, not as an interface to the CSS declarations.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Style-20001113/css.html#CSS-CSSStyleDeclaration

---

Fun fact: webkit seems to be doing a string match for `important`, so this works too:

```css
elem.style.setProperty('color', 'red', 'this is a really important rule');
```

---

And a tip: pick a better color pair next time, you're making it hard for the color blind to help :)

Comment: `!` is a delimiter and `important` is a keyword. delimiter is designed for browsers to parse through the styles. `important` is the "operation" should be performed. `super` or `very` are not part of any w3 standard and we developers should never use them. let's be clear and loud.

Comment: @RayCheng do you see the word "curiosity" up there? I just found that funny. Also, the `priority` argument for `setProperty` shouldn't include the `!`, but the function accepts `setProperty('color', 'red !important', null)` too (webkit at least).

Answer (score 0):

It could be that Firefox and Opera's behavior is more appropriate.

When you issue elem.style.color = 'red'; you did not turn off the "important" priority on the color, in which case it would make sense to change the color to red.  As far as why they choose to do it one way or another, I don't know.

Comment: One possibility is that FF/Opera simply overwrite the entire `color` property. Just because the old value had `!important` doesn't mean that the property was read-only. But then why don't Chrome/Safari/IE9 overwrite it too?

Comment: There's nothing about that in the specification. What happens in Chrome/Safari/IE9 when the priority is set (like in http://jsfiddle.net/4fn6h/9/)?

Comment: Maybe they never considered, or concerned themselves with the possibility developers might access the color in two different ways, style.color and style.setProperty, so did not feel compelled to address this inconsistency.  Maybe they anticipated development environments would have certain conventions of their own.  I don't know if these techniques normally intermingle in JavaScript libraries.

Comment: @Šime Vidas, `!important` can overrides normal css. normal css should never override `!important` css. the only time `!important` css gets overridden is when both user and author css contains `!important` and user css takes precedence. please see my post for details.

Answer (score 0):

Should it be possible to override a setProperty(...,'important') or not?
yes it should. but you have to do it with another `ele.style.setProperty` call. 
take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/DTgtx/) and you should see `red` in all modern browsers.

So, which browsers follow the standard here?
since `green` is set with `!important`, it should not be replaced with `red` since `red` is not set with `!important`. that means chrome, safari and IE9 are following the standard and firefox is NOT.

Comment: This is all correct, but you forgot that the issue at hand is the DOM interface for modifying style declarations, not just CSS. This behavior is opposite to direct manipulation of the `style` property, which doesn't allow for `!important` to be set.